# I am creating a program that finds the 6 numbers (regardless of the order) in 2 list which is generated randomly that is found in common but I'm stuck

Tags: python, list

I'm a beginner in Python, so I'm making a program that finds the **6 numbers** that is generated by random (regardless of the order) that it's the same as the first and second list (also generated by random). Where I'm stuck at is that I seem to can't print the numbers when **any digit** in 2 different lists that are same **regardless of the order**.

This is what I'm trying to make:

```
import random

random_number = range (1,50)

results = [] 
results_x = [] 
common_numbers = []

for i in range(1):   
number_a = random.sample(random_number, 6)  

if number_a not in results:
   results.append(number_a)

for i in range(1):   
number_b = random.sample(random_number, 6)  

if number_b not in results_x:
   results_x.append(number_b)

if results in results_x:   
common_numbers.append(results)

print(results) 
print(results_x) 
print(common_numbers)
```

The output is:

```
[[29, 44, 43, 10, 1, 31]]
[[29, 12, 10, 39, 38, 1]]
[]
```

Where 29, 10 and 1 is generated in both list but the last list I created that is the common_number list doesn't show 29, 10 and 1.

Answer (score 1):

Or use python sets, which have an `intersection()` method:

```
common_numbers = list(set(results).intersection(results_x))
```

Answer (score 1):

You have overcomplexified everything. You directly get lists from `sample`, so there is no reason to build new lists. What you want is simply (I made it reproducible with `random.seed`):

```
random.seed(00)

random_number = range (1,30)

results = random.sample(random_number, 6)  

results_x = random.sample(random_number, 6)  

common_numbers = [i for i in results if i in results_x]

print(results) 
print(results_x) 
print(common_numbers)
```

It gives:

```
[28, 13, 25, 14, 2, 9]
[17, 16, 13, 26, 10, 28]
[28, 13]
```

Comment: Thanks man, I didn't use the random.seed function since it generates numbers that are the same and it worked!!

Answer (score 0):

Well this is a really common error. This is because you cannot check if elements of a list is in another list just like that you need to edit code as following:
*Only the last part*

```
for i in results:
    if i in results_x:   
        common_numbers.append(results)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
first_list = [random.randint(0, 100) for i in range(6)] # generate the 6 numbers at random
second_list = first_list[:] # make a copy of the generated numbers
random.shuffle(second_list)
```

Result

```
>>> first_list
[10, 93, 77, 14, 91, 47]
>>> second_list
[47, 91, 10, 77, 93, 14]
```